I am trying Face recognizing in MAUI app using OpenCV , but it's always showing file not found error when i try to use CascadeClassifier xml file
I am trying Face recognizing in MAUI app using OpenCV , but it's always showing file not found error when i try to use CascadeClassifier xml file from my raw resource .
issue is in maui file handling required "Await" calling .
but Opencv CascadeClassifier not support async function  .
below is my code
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics;

namespace RapsysApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private VideoCapture _capture;
        private CascadeClassifier _faceDetector;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Initialize the face detector with a pre-trained model
            _faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"); 
            /////"Facing "File not found error at above line 
            /////( but file is added in resource folder and is readable with some basic await function ) 

            // Start the camera preview
            StartCameraPreview();
        }
       ....
       .....
}


Have you tried full path to the file?

I don't get the async part, you shouldn't await anything in the constructor.

Resources are not files

i try full path ( this xml file is readable for some basic read await function in same project)

My big doubt is Face recognition using Maui Program is work ?
